# Python: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I've installed the latest version of Numpy successfully and I'm using Python 3.4, I'm not understanding this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\LUdecomp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

header = txt.readline().split()
inputArray = map(float, txt.readline().split())
txt.close()

inputMat = np.mat(inputArray)
inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
inputMat.shape()

#takes q2data as input
def lu(A):
    #Decomposes a nxn matrix A by PA=LU and returns L, U and P.
    n = len(A)
    L = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]
    U = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]

    #Creates the pivoting matrix for m.
    n = len(A)
    ID = [[float(i == j) for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
    for j in xrange(n):
        row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(A[i][j]))
        if j != row:
            ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]
    p = ID

    #perform matrix multplication
    TA = zip(*A)
    A2 = [[sum(eP*ea for eP,ea in zip(P,a)) for a in TA] for P in p]

    for j in xrange(n):
        L[j, j] = 1.0
        for i in xrange(j+1):
            s1 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(i))
            U[i, j] = A2[i, j] - s1
        for i in xrange(j, n):
            s2 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(j))
            L[i, j] = (A2[i, j] - s2) / U[j, j]
    return (L, U, p)

print (lu(inputMat))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have installed a `64 bit` version of numpy and are using a `32 bit` version of python or vice versa. You can install a prebuilt  binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/

Should I be downloading Windows x86 MSI installer?  I'm pretty sure I downloaded the Windows x86-64 MSI installer the first time because it had 64 in the name

Comment: @JuniorMint, then you may have installed a 32 bit version of numpy, how did you install numpy?

Comment: Ah, I see http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/, I chose the win32 .exe, but I don't see any indicator for 64 bit?

Comment: There is one in the link I provided, you can install that with pip, just remove the old one first

Answer (score 0):

The smart solution I found is to simply do a **pip numpy upgrade**, **pip will uninstall the wrong 32 or 64 bit install with the needed bit install**. **Also, you can specify the version you want.**